# With JPA if you don't use @Inheritance with a parent/child does eclipse link use a default inheritance strategy?

Tags: jpa

I'm using JPA with spring data and eclipse link 2.5, with spring and java.

I currently have 2 entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER_TABLE")
public class Order
{.../*does not have an auditDate column*/}

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER_AUDIT_TABLE")
public class Child extends Parent
{
    @Column(name="AUDIT_DATE")
    private Date auditDate;
...
}
```

The issue is that when I call the parent JPA simple repository to query for a parent entity

```
Order order = orderRepository.findOne(orderId);
```

It gives me an error like the following.

```
Error Code: 904
Call: SELECT ID, ... AUDIT_DATE, FROM ORDER_TABLE WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [682]
...
ORA-00904: "AUDIT_DATE": invalid identifier
```

I was under the impression that if you left @Inheritance off then it wouldn't try to use any JPA Inheritance when interacting with the database.

However, based on the error I'm getting, it acts like I have `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` on Order. Which leads me to believe that it's adding it as a default in the background.

Is there any way for an @Entity to extend another @Entity in Java without JPA inheritance being applied in the background?

The reason I'm interested in this is because I want any modification to Order to also get applied to OrderAudit. So when a developer changes Order and they try to run the app, it will throw an error and let them know they need to alter the OrderAudit table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default is SINGLE_TABLE when javax.persistence.Inheritance is missing. This is documented for example in [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html):

> If the Inheritance annotation is not specified or if no inheritance
>   type is specified for an entity class hierarchy, the SINGLE_TABLE
>   mapping strategy is used.

If instead of this kind of inheritance only mappings from super class are needed, [@MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) is likely way to go.